# Dynamic fetch of URL based on the deployment environment

Tags: typescript, automation, automated-tests, typescript-generics, playwright

I have written a code to fetch URL dynamically using typescript and to use that to run my playwright test scripts. The problem is i dono whether the variables set for the URL fetch has to called in CI/CD tool or the code itself should fetch the url automatically when it pushed to different environnment.

Please help me , if there is a way that the code can automatically fetch the url of the environment that has been pushed.

**datahelper.ts**

```
import { BASE_URLS } from "./envConfig" // Import BASE_URLS from envConfig

interface Credentials {
  username: string
  password: string
}

export function getCredentials(): Credentials {
  const data = require("../data/loginData.json")
  const environment = process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ENV || "staging" // Use the deployment environment variable
  return data.credentials[BASE_URLS[environment]] || {} // Access BASE_URLS using the determined environment
}
```

**envconfig.ts**

```
export const BASE_URLS: Record<string, string> = {
  local: "example1.com",
  staging: "example2.com",
  production: "example3.com",
}
```

**Playwright test script**

```
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test"
import { getCredentials } from "./dataHelper"
import { BASE_URLS } from "./denvConfig"

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  const creds = getCredentials()
  const deploymentEnv = process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ENV || "staging"
  await page.goto(BASE_URLS[deploymentEnv])
  const signinmodule = await page.locator("div").filter({ hasText: "Hello Again!Welcome" }).nth(2)
  await signinmodule.getByRole("button", { name: "Login" }).click()
})
```

This is the code. Please suggest changes to automatically fetch the url on the playwright test script based on the deployment env.

Comment: What's wrong with the current approach? If `DEPLOYMENT_ENV` is set on the environment according to each environment, this should work.

Comment: i don't think there is something wrong. The approach is correct. But just need a second option if there is any other way?

Comment: @ggorlen One more doubt, is the `DEPLOYMENT_ENV` should be set via the CI/CD tool or it has to set in the code ?

Comment: This seems like the standard way to do it. It should be set by the environment, otherwise it isn't dynamic.

Comment: @ggorlen I have defined the environment in two place one is in test script `DEPLOYMENT_ENV` and one more in the `datahelper.ts` where its fetching the baseurl for the process and its defined with `environment` variable.
So i think this is what you mentioned in the previous comment. that this should be set by the `environment`

Comment: No, everything on `process.env` including `process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ENV` is set by the environment, which is the normal/correct approach. If you're concerned about having a bit of logic in two places, you can put it into the Playwright config as the [`baseUrl`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-base-url), but it doesn't change the fundamental approach of using environment variables to determine which URL to use.